# how to link login activity to some website?

Tags: android, authentication

i want to develop an app in which i want to make a login activity which should directly fill details in that website.
is it possible?
Or which method i should opt to link to some website.

P.S. I'm a beginner to android app development so please don't be very technical in reply.

thanks

Comment: Write web services at your website and access those web services in your android app to send and receive data from your web site server.

Comment: the website is not mine. i am designing it for somebody else and i can't ask him about this.